# How Create UIActivityIndicator computed property from a function in extension

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityindicatorview, uiactivity

I have managed to create a `UIActivityIndicatorView` extension for turning `animating` it to start and stop. However I would like make it better by using a `computed property` of type bool using a `get` and `set`. I have tried but can't think of way to do it. How could I refactor this.

```
extension UIActivityIndicatorView {
    func loadingIndicator(_ isLoading: Bool) {
        if isLoading {
            self.startAnimating()
        } else {
            self.stopAnimating()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you want to do? Do you just want to write function for start and stop animating?

Comment: This is unclear. What is the basis of the computed `Bool` property? What problem are you having? How will this property be used?

Comment: I wanted to start and stop animating using a getter and a setter. Thanks

Comment: @mandem112 That does not clarify your question at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `isAnimating` property of `UIActivityIndicatorView` as the backing value for `isLoading`. You just need to make sure that you control starting/stopping the animation correctly in the setter, that will set `isAnimating` and as a result, `isLoading` will also get set correctly.

```
extension UIActivityIndicatorView {
    var isLoading:Bool {
        get {
            return isAnimating
        } set {
            if newValue {
                self.startAnimating()
            } else {
                self.stopAnimating()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can optimize your code by this way:

```
extension UIActivityIndicatorView {
    var isLoading:Bool {
        get {
            return isAnimating
        } set {
            newValue ? startAnimating() : stopAnimating()
        }
    }
}
```